# Android : Video Intent Opening Error : Source not found

Tags: android, video, android-intent, video-player

I am trying to use the intent to select a video which I want to play using videoplayer. I am not able to get the intent working instead i am getting the Source Not Found error.

Thanks for your help.

This is my code :

Manifest

```
 <application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    <activity
        android:name="SurfaceActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Code:

```
   public class SurfaceActivity extends Activity implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener, OnPreparedListener, MediaController.MediaPlayerControl
{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
 loadVideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Load);
    //  surface.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
     loadVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent();

            intent.setType("video/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Video File to Play"), 0);
        }
    });



}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{

        if (requestCode == 0)
        {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                Uri sourceUri = data.getData();
                String source = getPath(sourceUri);

                //startPlayback(source);
                startPlaying(source); 
            }
        }


}
```

}

Comment: It doesn't look like you're adding the desired video's URI to the intent you're sending.

Comment: I want to select dynamic video ..allowing the user to select the video. I saw an example where they are doing something similar. But my code is not allowing me to select any video. I could see it opens the selection area but not letting me to select I get the source not found error. Also it is not coming to the breakpoint onActivityResult method.